# Add black border to selected cell of collection view adn remove borders from other unselected cells of collection view

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, border

I have 7 cells in collection view .I want when user selects cell1,the border of cell changes to black color and other cells from 0 to 6 excluding 1 ,appears with clear border color.

For,that I am doing the following:-

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        imagePickerCell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
        imagePickerCell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell =  [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSLog(@"deselected cell on imagepickerVC %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.0f;
        cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];

}
```

But,it doesn't work properly as if i click on 1st cells then 1 st will be black others will be clear but when i click 6th cell and then get back to 1st ,it shows 1st and 6 th both with black borders.
Kindly help me to resolve this and add border to only selected cell while removing borders from other unselected cells.

Any kind of help and suggestion would be appreciated .Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cells are reused. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add/remove also the the border if needed. You could also use a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and override it's `setSelected:` to show/hide the border.

Comment: What exactly I am suppose to do...can you share some code or explained example for that?